# Problems making an UIImageView opaque on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, uiimageview, quartz-graphics

Doing as little alpha blending as possible is an important performance consideration for table view cells on the iPhone. I have table cells that are largely comprised of one big image view. I have set the UIImageView to be opaque, in both Interface Builder and programmatically, but the CoreAnimation instrument still shows that it is being alpha-blended.

Is there a way to make UIImageViews actually opaque, or am I going to have to do custom drawing to keep from blending?

Comment: What kind of image are you loading in your view? If it's a PNG or other format with alpha support, Core Animation may be blending the view because of its image.

Comment: It is a PNG image (recommended iPhone image format, IIRC), but it doesn't have any transparent pixels.

Comment: Are they alpha blending the actual view or the contents of the view? Do any of the options in the inspector allow you to set the background, color, or style to be opaque? Is it a property you can set at runtime?

Comment: Sorry, improved the question because you aren't asking how to make things transparent you are having a problem with the opacity property not working as it should be

Comment: I'm doing custom drawing. i experienced the same problem and was unable to fix it without resorting to drawRect

Comment: Putting aside the question as asked for a moment, are you running into actual performance problems?  That is, I use alpha-blended views in my table cells *all the time*, and it flows quite smoothly.  In fact, I have a couple of apps where the cell, itself, is transparent (so the table-background shows through), with no problems, even on older (3G) hardware.  I'm just suggesting that you not put too much effort into solving something if it's not really a problem for you.

Comment: Are you setting your actual cells to be transparent in -willDisplayCell?

Comment: Does the image have an alpha channel? Even if there are no transparent pixels, there is a large chance of an alpha channel being present. Try removing it.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that your image contains alpha channel. Although the image is opaque, iOS still treats it as semi-transparent. Try to remove this alpha channel using Photoshop by going to: Layer > Background From Layer

Answer (score 0):

`[yourImageView setOpaque:YES];`

Comment: `setOpaque` is a hint to the drawing system. When testing it shows to have no effect in this case.